# change the type of font for the logo

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have this website that contains the logo, and I want to call the site "Bakerita", but how can I change the font type for this word?
I opened the main website, but I couldn't find any information to be able to change the font type.

App.vue:

```
<template>
<div>
    <v-app-bar
      color="deep-purple accent-4"
    >
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>Bakerita</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn icon>
        <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn icon>
        <v-icon>mdi-filter</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn icon>
        <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="drawer"
      absolute
      bottom
      temporary
    >
      <v-list
        nav
        dense
      >
        <v-list-item-group
          v-model="group"
          active-class="deep-purple--text text--accent-4"
        >
          <v-list-item>
            <v-list-item-title>Foo</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-list-item>
            <v-list-item-title>Bar</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-list-item>
            <v-list-item-title>Fizz</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-list-item>
            <v-list-item-title>Buzz</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list-item-group>
      </v-list>
        </v-navigation-drawer>
    </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      data(){
        return{
          drawer:false
        }
      }
    };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [component api](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-toolbar-title/) there's no prop to customize the style, but you could wrap your title with a div and give it the style that you want :

```
<v-toolbar-title>
  <div style="font-size:24pt">
    Bakerita
  </div>
</v-toolbar-title>
```

Comment: from where can i get type of font? website or anyThing.

Comment: from [dafont](http://www.dafont.com/) or [google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/)

Comment: I use this two website and i use "Rollanda" Type.
but when i write like this:
.myfont {
  font-family: 'Rollanda'
}
I can't get Result.
What can i do?
@anonymous dev

Comment: you should add it as font-face by including the file in your css

Comment: can you explain more please

Comment: you could check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp) for more details